# ansible jar check if already installed

Tags: tomcat, jar, ansible

i'm having a jar file that installs tomcat with a website. so i have following tasks `download jar file`, `install jar` file and `delete jar file`. however i want ansible to tell that it is already installed instead of downloading and trying to install again. how can i achieve such?

```
- name: Downloading installer
  get_url:
  url: http://[URl]/installfile.jar
  dest: "/opt"

- name: Installing jar file
  shell: java -jar "/opt/installfile.jar"

- name: Removing installer
  file:
  state: absent
  path: "/opt/installfile.jar"
```

Comment: You need to decide how you want to check the package is installed. Whether you want to check for a presence of some file, or run an executable and check the output, or manually set a flag in a file on the target server. I'm not sure anyone but you can do it. When you decide what you want, and have a specific problem then ask for help on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `creates` arg on the install task at least, so that the java program will only run when certain file does not yet exist. Ansible will create such file  the first time the task runs.

Something like:

```
- name: Installing jar file
  shell: java -jar "/opt/installfile.jar"
  args:
    creates: /opt/installfile-check
```

Or if you want to condition the three tasks to run only when Tomcat is not installed, you need to first run a program that checks whether it is installed and register its result in a variable that other tasks can use to determine if they need to run using `when`.

```
- name: Check to see if Tomcat is installed
  shell: "command --that --checks" # Just an example, obviously
  register: tomcat_is_installed
```

You can then include the Tomcat playbook only when it is not installed:

```
- name: This playbook will only be included when Tomcat is not installed
  include: tomcat-playbook.yml
  when: tomcat_is_installed.rc != 0
```